# Getting the error " @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.15.0): Connection WebChannel transport errored" in React Native Cloud Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a react native application. I am trying to simply store data into cloud Firestore. I followed the documentation while setting up the cloud Firestore but still getting the error.
I have already included firebase Google Auth and Phone auth already in my project and they are working perfectly.

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '***********',
  authDomain: '***********',
  databaseURL: '************',
  projectId: '*********',
  storageBucket: '***********',
  messagingSenderId: '**********',
  appId: '*******************',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
};

/* if (!firebase.apps.length) { */
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
    export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

This is config.js file.

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db } from '../components/config';
```

This is how I imported the database and firestore in one of the screens.

```
try {
        console.log("I tried to add data to the database")
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
          first: "Ada",
          last: "Lovelace",
          born: 1815
        });
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
      }
```

This is how I tried sending data to firestore.
Everything was done according to documentation.

I am getting this error

```
 [2023-01-04T10:11:40.422Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.15.0): Connection WebChannel transport errored: {"defaultPrevented": false, "g": {"A": true, "J": null, "R": [Circular], "g": {"$": true, "$a": 5000, "A": 3, "B": null, "C": 0, "Ca": "FNfAYYs2MaCorbMq6Mf1R9j8iPOgyaJ7pQhysEk5dtQ", "D": "gsessionid", "Ea": -1, "F": [U], "Fa": 12, "G": 0, "Ga": false, "H": true, "Ia": [ud], "J": "nFh02neRvgNxOoZ0mmVvKQ", "K": 45000, "L": false, "M": true, "O": true, "P": false, "R": 0, "U": [Object], "V": 0, "W": 93697, "Y": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "aa": 4, "ab": false, "ba": false, "bb": false, "cb": 2, "eb": 1, "fb": 10000, "g": null, "h": [pd], "i": [Array], "j": [Sb], "l": [Z], "la": [Object], "m": null, "ma": undefined, "na": "", "o": null, "oa": null, "pa": 8, "s": null, "sa": -1, "u": null, "ua": undefined, "v": null, "va": [U], "wa": 600000}, "h": {"database": "projects/cabshare-44794/databases/[object Object]"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "status": 1, "target": {"A": true, "J": null, "R": [Circular], "g": {"$": true, "$a": 5000, "A": 3, "B": null, "C": 0, "Ca": "FNfAYYs2MaCorbMq6Mf1R9j8iPOgyaJ7pQhysEk5dtQ", "D": "gsessionid", "Ea": -1, "F": [U], "Fa": 12, "G": 0, "Ga": false, "H": true, "Ia": [ud], "J": "nFh02neRvgNxOoZ0mmVvKQ", "K": 45000, "L": false, "M": true, "O": true, "P": false, "R": 0, "U": [Object], "V": 0, "W": 93697, "Y": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "aa": 4, "ab": false, "ba": false, "bb": false, "cb": 2, "eb": 1, "fb": 10000, "g": null, "h": [pd], "i": [Array], "j": [Sb], "l": [Z], "la": [Object], "m": null, "ma": undefined, "na": "", "o": null, "oa": null, "pa": 8, "s": null, "sa": -1, "u": null, "ua": undefined, "v": null, "va": [U], "wa": 600000}, "h": {"database": "projects/cabshare-44794/databases/[object Object]"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "type": "c"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

I was using this command to install firebase.

> npm install firebase@9.13.0 --save

Instead use the commands given below

## Install & setup the app module

yarn add @react-native-firebase/app

## Install the firestore module

yarn add @react-native-firebase/firestore

This solved the issue for me. Hopefully it works for you too!

For more details follow the firebase documentation:
https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage